# iOS: Which Webview should be used 10.0 Onwards

Tags: ios

I have to use cookies which get stored from the login session, webview creates. I can access cookies from UIWebview and store it in UserDefaults.  Now, as UIWebview is deprecated I am thinking to switch to the other Webviews like WKWebview or SFSafariViewController which also provide other features to enable trust and challenges. It has to be secure as well.

Comment: Use SFSafariViewController..Safari features such as Reader, AutoFill, Fraudulent Website Detection, and content blocking. In iOS 9 and 10, it shares cookies and other website data with Safari. The user's activity and interaction with SFSafariViewController are not visible to your app, which cannot access AutoFill data, browsing history, or website data. You do not need to secure data between your app and Safari. If you would like to share data between your app and Safari in iOS 11 and later, so it is easier for a user to log in only one time, use SFAuthenticationSession instead.

Comment: So, I have to store the cookies from Webview after successful login and send them over to every rest API call going forward . Would this work with SFSafariViewController ?